# Gunn diode operation frequency

Tags: diodes, oscillator, microwave

Gunn diodes are usually specified to work within a range of frequencies, e.g ~10GHz. I can easily understand why there is an upper bound for the frequency of operation of a Gunn diode, but I can't figure out why there is a lower bound: after all, what is used is the negative resistance of the diode: what prevent us to use this negative resistance at frequencies as low as 100hz, beside the fact that it would be very stupid to use a Gunn diode at such frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limitations of  self resonant choke frequency>10Ghz and high enough L to isolate the DC bias from loading the negative resistance limits the LF cutoff.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat cryptic for me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: you have to apply a low impedance DC voltage to bias at -Z threshold  that is voltage source is high Z  in GHz range with a suitable choke.  unfortunately interwinding capacitance or leakage C increases with L which reduces f self resonant frequency so L must be small (nH) and thus fMin is large.

Comment: I think I understand. But why is it ideally necessary to apply a high impedance DC voltage to bias the diode ?

Comment: if a voltage source with Low Z is  applied to a resonator, it lowers the Q or gain and stops oscillating . Normally Q is the ratio of effective real/reactive for impedance and expressed by f/-3dB BW . This applies to LC resonators with R load as well. for parallel mode.

Comment: cheers mike....tony